# Jython/Python - cannot retain variables between functions

Tags: python, jython, jes

Writing a very basic text based game for uni...
Trying to have a global variable or a "key" that will allow access to certain areas if if has been "found" 
ie. When found key=1. Trying to determine ownership (or otherwise) for result when attempting room access with the following code:
(I'll only include the related code parts)

```
def playGame(): 
  key = 0 
  location = "Porch"
  showIntroduction()
  while not (location == "Exit") :
    showRoom(location)
    direction = requestString("Which direction?")
    location = pickRoom(direction , location)

def showRoom(location):
  if location == "Porch":
    showPorch()
  if location == "Entryway":
    showEntryway()
 if location == "Kitchen":
    if direction == "north":
      return "DiningRoom"
    if direction == "west":
      if key == 1:
        return "Stairs"
      else:
        printNow("You do not possess the Skeleton Key!")
        return "Kitchen"
    if direction == "south":
      return "Entryway"

def showLR():
  if key == 0:
    printNow("...")
    printNow("You enter the living room; dust covers the fireplace.")
    printNow("Cobwebs shield a great armchair and it's contents from view.")
    printNow("You spot an object glinting on the mantle, the dim light     casting flickering shadows all around.")
    printNow("The only exit lies behind, to the west")
    printNow("...")
  if key == 1:
    printNow("...")
    printNow("The living room shimmers in the dappled light.")
    printNow("Cobwebs shield a great armchair and it's contents from view.")
    printNow("The key in your pocket feels warm, or is it just your imagination?")
    printNow("The only exit lies behind, to the west")
    printNow("...")
```

Hope the above makes sense, most functions (showEntryway() showPorch()) have been omitted but they do similar things to showLR().

I'm trying to get the "key" to work as a variable, every time i enter the LivingRoom and it runs:

```
if key == 0:
```

I get an error saying variable not found, the initial value is not carried from playGame()...\

Hope this is understandable, any assistance would be gratefully received!!!! Thanks
TG

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options: Make key a `global` variable, or pass it in as a second parameter.

For the global style, you need to have a `global key` line in functions where you also want to update it (i.e. finding the key).

Global style:

```
key = 0

def playGame(): 
  global key
  key = 0
  location = "Porch"
  showIntroduction()
  while not (location == "Exit") :
    showRoom(location)
    direction = requestString("Which direction?")
    location = pickRoom(direction , location)

def showRoom(location):
  if location == "Porch":
    showPorch()
  if location == "Entryway":
    showEntryway()
 if location == "Kitchen":
    if direction == "north":
      return "DiningRoom"
    if direction == "west":
      if key == 1:
        return "Stairs"
      else:
        printNow("You do not possess the Skeleton Key!")
        return "Kitchen"
    if direction == "south":
      return "Entryway"

def showLR():
  if key == 0:
    printNow("...")
    printNow("You enter the living room; dust covers the fireplace.")
    printNow("Cobwebs shield a great armchair and it's contents from view.")
    printNow("You spot an object glinting on the mantle, the dim light     casting flickering shadows all around.")
    printNow("The only exit lies behind, to the west")
    printNow("...")
  if key == 1:
    printNow("...")
    printNow("The living room shimmers in the dappled light.")
    printNow("Cobwebs shield a great armchair and it's contents from view.")
    printNow("The key in your pocket feels warm, or is it just your imagination?")
    printNow("The only exit lies behind, to the west")
    printNow("...")
```

Alternatively, you can maintain a key variable of sorts, and pass it into each function ("finding" the key is then a different beast). Think about how you would update the `key` variable if it wasn't global. I'll leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the global function. Perfect solution, thank you very much sir!